# Как получить данные типа Object из Firestore

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firestore

Использую в своем проекте бд Cloud Firestore.
В документе есть данные типа object, в котором еще несколько таких же object, в которых уже в свою очередь несколько String. Показано на рисунке ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, у меня получилось всё это получить в один объект, всё сразу. Выводил результат в логи.

```
object = document.getData();
```

Если сделать как при получении уникального поля из документа, то переменная остается пустой. Да даже просто при выводе в логи без переменной, тоже пустые фигурные скобки показывает {} показывает. Но так использовал только с полями типа String.

```
object = document.getData().get("Среда");
```

String работает нормально, но разделять строку, как мне кажется, не совсем правильно.

```
String timetable = document.getData().get("Среда").toString();
```

Так вот можно ли как-то грамотно это сделать? Получить все объекты, в том числе и вложенные отдельно? Или хотя бы чтобы можно было получать эти поля не разделяя строки?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: На самом деле получилось object = document.getData().get("Среда");
Теперь в нем такое: {Англ. язык={Время=10:00-11:30, Кабинет=25}, Предмет1={Время=12:00-13:30, Кабинет=1}}
Как можно разделить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное удачное решение было заменить объекты на коллекции и документы. Получилась более сложная иерархия.